# Vue.js and django MIME Type Issue

Tags: javascript, django, vue.js, heroku, mime-types

I'm deploying to heroku a vue.js app nested inside a django project. I followed this guide verbatim

https://medium.com/@williamgnlee/simple-integrated-django-vue-js-web-application-configured-for-heroku-deployment-c4bd2b37aa70

Build to heroku succeeds, and the website loads -- the API portion of the site in question, for example, is fully viewable.

https://heseltime.herokuapp.com/api_example/

But I am not able to access the vue.js app because there is a MIME type issue. Error log:

```
The resource from “https://heseltime.herokuapp.com/static/css/app.48175cc56e52e020bf178616c0977374.css” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
```

https://heseltime.herokuapp.com/ is where the vue.js is supposed to be, as per urls.py in my django project

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.conf.urls import url

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html')),
    path('api_example', include('api_example.urls')),
]
```

When I ssh into the heroku side I find the files in the right staticfiles location as per my settings.py from django

```
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'dist/static'),
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = False
```

The html of the website is loaded as

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
    <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <title>heseltime</title>
    <link href=/static/css/app.48175cc56e52e020bf178616c0977374.css rel=stylesheet>
</head>
<body>
    <div id=app></div>
    <script type=text/javascript src=/static/js/manifest.2ae2e69a05c33dfc65f8.js></script>
    <script type=text/javascript src=/static/js/vendor.7e9567d6dec21d8821f2.js></script>
    <script type=text/javascript src=/static/js/app.f5b30ee15ad2f9646708.js></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This looks good to me (?) -- Could this be a CORSHeaders issue?

Comment: requests for all your `css` and `js` result in not found - obviously the server sends an html response with the "file not found" message, which is why the mime type mismatch - the problem is those files do not exist, nothing to do with CORS since the request is same origin

Comment: thank you, you were right. The issue was also caused by missing middleware for white noise. (forgot to add to middleware in settings.py. once that line is added, the staticfiles/ are made available correctly.)